# Absolute extremes of a function enclosed in the region of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I'm stuck with the following problem:

> Find the absolute extremes of the function
> $$
> f\left(x,y\right)=\ln\left(4x^2+y^2+4\right)+\int _0^x\frac{2t}{t^4+1}dt
> $$
> in the region $D$ enclosed by the ellipse
> $$
> \frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1.
> $$

**What I've done so far**

First we recognize

$\int _0^x\frac{2t}{t^4+1}dt=\arctan \left(x^2\right)$

So

$f\left(x,\:y\right)=ln\left(4x^2+y^2+4\right)+\arctan \:\left(x^2\right)$

If let be using lagrange's multipliers

$g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{y^2}{4}-1$

$∇f\left(x,y\right)=\lambda ∇g\left(x,y\right)$

$g(x,y)=c$

The systems of equations is the following

$\frac{8x}{4x^2+y^2+4}+\frac{2x}{x^4+1}=\lambda 2x$

$\frac{2y}{4x^2+y^2+4}=\frac{\lambda y}{2}$

$\frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$

And shamely I'm still dealing with it I already check the solutions in Wolfram Alpha but I want to derive it analytically or seeing how is done.

So I ask for any advice on that, and check if what I've done so far is correct. (Sorry for the basic of the question)

Comment: Hints: Multiply the last equation by $4$ and replace that expression everywhere.  From the second equation, either $y=0$ or you can cancel $y$ - use cases.

Comment: You seem to be solving the problem on the boundary only.  Why shouldn't the extrema occur in the interior of the ellipse?

Comment: This does not require Lagrange Multiplier method. You know $x^2 \leq 1$. So max $\arctan(x^2) = \pi/4$. But if you want to use Lagrange, only do it for this part. $\ln\left(4x^2+y^2+4\right) = \ln (4(x^2 + y^2/4) + 4) \leq \ln 8$

Comment: So it is clear that absolute maximum is at $(\pm 1, 0)$

Comment: So it is just a matter of showing maximum of both terms individually and that both can be achieved simultaneously.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! it worked hehe and also thanks to math lover for your comments,  I'm going to do it also in that way, thanks.